# Node access audit by user?

Tags: 8, nodes, users

I have a unique need to log all attempts, with timestamps, by all users to access nodes of a given content type in Drupal 8/9.

We wish to use our existing Drupal site to collect submissions of proposals from potential vendors, and there is a restriction that no one internally is able to view those submissions until after the close date of our invitation.  If there is a way to handle that construct, that is acceptable, but it sounds complicated.

The alternative (and the subject of this message) is that we find a way to audit access to specific nodes, so that if someone is reviewing our purchasing or evaluation processes, we can run a report that shows when each user accessed the node and verify that no one has accessed the node since its creation.

Note that these nodes will only be viewed by one small and specific user group and this is the only content type that would need to be tracked in such a way; there would only be a handful of users and a handful of nodes involved.

Comment: So you know your going to have do some development work to get this done.
logging is not hard to do see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Alogger/8.2.x and look at hook_entity_view to help with preventing the access